# C# put date into program when compiled

Tags: c#

I was thinking about how to create a program that would only be valid for X period of time, (within a C# app).

What I was thinking was that you would have the current date as a constant inside the program and it would check to see if it is X days older than that.  Naturally I do not want to store the date, or the X outside of the program as it can be tampered with.

What I also do not want to manually change this regularly and recompile and deploy it.  So is there a way to set a variable to be the current date when it is compiled?

I could have a batch file that would compile it and deploy the new exe to the distribution server.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Precompilation directives are your key here. You could create a constant in your application and have it set when you compile.

Make sure you obfuscate your code, however. Someone could disassemble it easily and tamper with the constant. Another solution is to have your software "phone home" to register itself. That way, the registration info is stored on your server and not their machine. There are also third party packages that perform the same security as you're looking for, but they are **expensive**!

Comment: cool idea.  Obfuscate is a must (not that I know how yet! :p).. thanks

Comment: Your also right about the disassemble issue, but within C# not sure there's a great way to avoid that.

Answer (score 5):

Check out AssemblyInfo.cs file in the Properties folder in your project:

```
// You can specify all the values or you can default the Build and Revision Numbers 
// by using the '*' as shown below:
// [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

Change this to:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

Then, elsewhere in the assembly, use this:

```
System.Version MyVersion = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;

// MyVersion.Build = days after 2000-01-01
// MyVersion.Revision*2 = seconds after 0-hour  (NEVER daylight saving time)
DateTime MyTime = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1).AddDays(MyVersion.Build).AddSeconds(MyVersion.Revision * 2);
return string.Format("Version:{0}  Compiled:{1:s}", MyVersion, MyTime);
```

Comment: That's a good way to find when the assembly was compiled easily; it is, however, suspect to the same decompilation/recompilation problems every other method of doing this also has...

Comment: If they're decompiling your code to get your date... they can decompile your code to call your code.  Obscuring this date is a false measure and offers no protection.

Comment: thats why i would recommend the "phone home" method

Comment: Doesn't phonehome just trade the problem?  Now, you have to manage their identity, which they can modify.

Comment: They can also modify the home to which they are phoning.

Comment: Be aware that, according to this post : http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/determining-build-date-the-hard-way.html, "the IDE does not update the build number every time you build a solution. Visual Studio only increments the build and revision number when the solution is closed and reopened."

Answer (score 3):

I would go with the "Phone home"-variant. And make that call important. ;)
I mean, some important function in your program (some calculation maybe?) will take place on the server. So if the user decompile the program and remove that "call home" it will render the program useless.

I know that not all programs have those specifications that makes this possible but more than you think in general.

Comment: Phone home is a good idea.. but from what you have all said I realize it is not an easy answer at all.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

From within your automated build process (you do use an automated build process, right?), had a simple app which generates a 1-line C# class

```
 public struct TimeLimit { public DateTime Date = new DateTime(2009,1,1); }
```

changing the date automatically, and compile.

Then just refer to TimeLimit.Date in your app.

Comment: ...but maybe obsfucate and not call it TimeLimit! ;)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a 3 year old question, but just to add my 2 cents. We use a "DateLimit" hard coded in a structure as suggested by James Curran.

But we also use that same "Date" as a simple key to "crypt" and "Decrypt" (more Code and decode) all strings, labels, messages. If some people (We call them Cheaters) want to change the expiration date, They will have to go thru the whole assembly to reenter all those string correctly for the new expiration date. It's not perfect, but the cost to us is now near zero and the cost for the Cheaters is high.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that you have the date in a separate, strong named assembly - then at least the malevolent user will find it hard to disassemble, edit and get your program to use it. Is there a way to have two assemblies validating each other based on strong names?

We kind of use this as a first step in our license control for one of our components. If the calling assembly has the same fingerprint as the license controlled one, we assume that it's being used within our own software and licensing is bypassed. If the calling assembly has a different fingerprint or no print at all, normal license checka are carried through. When I come to think of it, our users could probably disassemble, compile without strong naming and bypass licensing. But then again, all our assemblies are shipped as x86, not CIL - would that change anything?

Our experience is that if you're dealing with corporate customers, no-one can bear the hassle of tampering with your stuff, especially since there is a risk in getting caught. A little goes a long way, our current licensing solution is pretty outdated (the package includes examples for VC5!) but has been a high enough hurdle so far. With consumers, on the other hand, I can imagine that it's a bigger threat.

My initial suggestion seems to spawn more questions that answers - perhaps not that helpful after all. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with .Net is that it would be easy to decompile and change the date you want to use has constant. You might need to think to something else.

You could write it in the registry but then the people will edit this value.

They aren't a perfect solution but to have an account that validate with an external (web) server is a good idea.