# Set constant when compiling in C#

Tags: c#, xna

I am using XNA 3.1 to develop a small game and I want to add the following two features:

1) Increment the build value every time I compile
2) Set the date/time of compilation

I want to be able to set the Date/Time of compile in the Window Title (like Crysis)
I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320887/c-put-date-into-program-when-compiled) but I need more details. I am using Visual Studio 2008.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the assembly version to be automatically updated when you build by setting it's build number and revision number to * in your AssembyInfo.cs file:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
```

Now the build number can be read from the assembly and you can use this to determine the date when your program was built. Check the documentation for the [AssemblyVersionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k49w9389.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Yep, this is exactly what I ended up using. Here is the formula to convert it into DateTime: Datetime timeCompiled = new DateTime (build * TimeSpan.TicksPerDay + revision * TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond * 2).AddYears (1999); Note that Daylight savings time is ignored.

Comment: I did some checks and there may be a slight problem using the assembly version. You may see that the version is only updated the first time you compile after starting visual studio.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [this](http://autobuildversion.codeplex.com/). It should do all that you want.

Comment: This is also a useful thing to look into.